# Asp.net mvc compiler error when trying to invoke View Component from view page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I am trying to create my first View Component in my MVC project but have come to a halt. When I try to invoke my View Component from the razor view page I get an error that states: "The name 'await' does not exist in the current context".

Code I use to call the View Component:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Example")
```

View Component class:

```
namespace MyWebApp.ViewComponents
{
    public class ExampleViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {
            var user = Account.GetCurrent();

            return View(user);
        }
    }
}
```

View Component razor view file location: `Views/Shared/Components/Example/Default.cshtml`

View Component class file location: `ViewComponents/ExampleViewComponent.cs`

I have mostly been following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1

**SOLVED : Check comments**

Comment: Where are you calling the View component ? Is it inside a razor view file ?

Comment: yes, inside Views/Home/Index.cshtml

Comment: Which MVC version you're using? `@await Component.InvokeAsync("Example")` works only for Core MVC, in previous versions you need child actions (marked as `ChildActionOnlyAttribute`).

Comment: Turns out it's a asp.net application and not asp.net core. Thanks for the heads up. created a child action method now and works fine :)