# How to Invoke ViewComponents from View in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to Invoke Components from inside the view, but keep getting errors. And online I can only find examples working with ASP.NET Core, but I am not using Core.

This is my View:

```
@model BeestjeOpJeFeestje.Models.BoekingProces

<h2>Boeken</h2>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-9" style="padding: 0">
        @switch (Model.Boeking.BoekingStatus)
        {
            case BeestjeOpJeFeestje.Models.BoekingStatus.Beestjes:
                if (TempData["error"] != null)
                {
                    <span class="text-danger">@TempData["error"]</span>
                }
                @await Component.InvokeAsync("BeestjesKiezen", @Model);
                break;
            case BeestjeOpJeFeestje.Models.BoekingStatus.Accessoires:
                @await Component.InvokeAsync("AccessoiresKiezen", @Model);
                break;
            case BeestjeOpJeFeestje.Models.BoekingStatus.Informatie:
                @await Component.InvokeAsync("Klantgegevens", @Model);
                break;
            case BeestjeOpJeFeestje.Models.BoekingStatus.Bevestiging:
                @await Component.InvokeAsync("Bevestiging", @Model);
                break;
        }
    </div>
    <div class="col col-3">
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("BookingDetail", @Model)
    </div>
</div>
```

But it results in the errors that 'await' and 'Component' not exists in the current context.
[image]

Can someone maybe help me with the correct syntax? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try await without @ inside switch?

Comment: When I Try it without the @ The Component error stays the same. And the await errors becomes: 'The 'await operator can only be used within an async method...''

Comment: Are you referencing static class Component with using, because I don't see it in your code.

Comment: No I do not. But I am not really sure why this isn't working. I have this exact code in a Core project and there it is working fine. Could it be that it just is not possible in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This question has been answered before, the Component Static class is not available in ASP.NET MVC. It is only available with Core;
   [Asp.net mvc compiler error when trying to invoke View Component from view page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52373631/asp-net-mvc-compiler-error-when-trying-to-invoke-view-component-from-view-page)

---

2. It is mentioned in the documentation that it is similar to a partial view, hence use that instead. But this won't have the asynchronous feature, the server will always wait for this rendering to finish before proceeding.

```
@{
    Html.RenderPartial("BeestjesKiezen", Model);
}
```

---

3. Meanwhile, rendering parts of your page asynchronously can be done via ajax/jquery.
   See the answer here;
   [How to render a partial view asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913836/how-to-render-a-partial-view-asynchronously)

Comment: I couldn't figure the async loading out, so i went ahead an made everything synchronous. It all works fine now.